# Solving a separable differential equation: $xy' = (1-4x^2)\tan(y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $\tan(y)$ to $y$? I can't solve this.

$$ xy' = (1-4x^2)\tan(y)$$
$$ x \frac{dy}{dx} = (1-4x^2)\tan(y)  $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{\tan(y)} dy = \int \frac{(1-4x^2)}{x} dx  $$
$$ \ln|\tan(y)| = \ln|x| - 2x^2 + C$$
$$ \tan(y) = xe^{-2x^2+C}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to solve $\tan(y)$ to $y$? I can't solve this.*

**Hint**. You may use 
$$
\arctan (\tan (y))=y,\quad y \in \left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right).
$$

**Edit**. There is a mistake in your steps above, you rather have
$$
\int \frac1{\tan (y)}\:dy=\int \frac{\cos (y)}{\sin (y)}\:dy=\ln \left|\:\sin (y)\:\right|
$$ giving
$$
\ln \left|\:\sin (y)\:\right|=\ln |x|-2x^2+C
$$ that is
$$
\sin (y)=\pm e^C x\:e^{-2x^2}
$$ leading to
$$
y=n\pi \pm \arcsin \left(e^C x\:e^{-2x^2} \right), \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$